# Condition on the same line. The problem is that it doesn't print the next line

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-statements

The output is "Hello. I'm Santiago", but I would like to print `"Hello. I'm Santiago and i love Python`". I have never used conditions on the same line. I'm new to Python.

The 2 + 2 condition is just a simple example. I wish if the condition is true then I get the output "Hello. I'm Michael and i love Python"? I need `"\"` to write in each different staff as I did.

I don't want to use the solution `f"{b}" f"{c}" if 2+2 == 4 else ""`, but keep the code structure as in the question

How can I solve?

```
a = "Hello. "
b = "I'm Santy"
c = " and i love Python"


x = f"{a}" \
    f"{b}" if 2+2 == 4 else "" \
    f"{c}"

print(x)
```

Comment: You are trying to get too fancy and do too much in a single line. Break the assignment into smaller steps to build up the string.

Comment: What do you expect to get if the condition is false?

Comment: "..., but keep the code structure as in the question" This constraint seems to block you from making a working solution. I suggest you figure out a different structure that actually works.

Comment: "Readability counts" (c) Zen of Python. This is not very readable. Just write a normal if-else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `\` at the end of each line doesn't do what you think it does. The `""` is concatenated with the `f"{c}"` before the `if...else` is evaluated.

One way to solve this is to add litera `+`es to concatenate the strings. You also need to add parentheses to force the correct order of operations.

```
x = f"{a}" + \
    (f"{b}" if 2+2 == 4 else "") + \
    f"{c}"
```

But then you don't need `f""`:

```
x = a + \
    (b if 2+2 == 4 else "") + \
    c
```

While this is fine for investigating python out of intellectual curiosity, I strongly recommend that you avoid trying to do everything in a single statement. Instead, break up your logic into discreet steps that concatenate strings together. Use if statements rather than if expressions for conditional parts of the string. In general, KISS it (Keep It Simple Stupid).

Comment: Unfortunately I need f "", because this small piece of code in my application is part of a larger code that necessarily includes f "", otherwise it won't work. Thank you

Comment: @SantiagoE.98 Whether to use `f""` or not is irrelevant to your question. Since your example starts with strings already, it isn't needed, but if you are doing other formatting in your actual code, you can leave it. The main issue here is that you need to use `+` and `()` to do what you want.

Comment: This doesn't actually work... try changing the condition to `False`

Comment: @Nick Did you refresh to see the most recent version where I added parentheses? I'm making a guess what the OP wants, so maybe it doesn't "work". But then we need a better definition of what "working" is in this case.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I understand. Your solution works well. Is there also a way to solve by NOT writing else "" or ""?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, and it gives `'Hello.  and i love Python'` if the condition is false. See my answer...

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I mean not to write the two quotes (> ""), but to use another solution? I just need "if 2 + 2 == 4"

Comment: @Nick Yes, I'm making a guess as to the desired result. You are probably right that I am not getting what the OP wants, but the purpose for the condition is unclear. The OP doesn't really make clear what they want the result to be in each case.

Comment: @SantiagoE.98 " Is there also a way to solve by NOT writing else "" or ""?" That depends on what you want. As I say in the final paragraph, you should use an `if` statement rather than an `if` expression. Then build up the string you want in multiple steps instead of trying to do it all at once.

Comment: @SantiagoE.98 " I just need "if 2 + 2 == 4"" Why? This condition will always be true. I assume it is a place holder for something more complicated. But by simplifying, you are probably leaving out important details that would allow me to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I didn't want to go into details so as not to lengthen the question. Instead of 2 + 2 == 4, I will have to insert a condition of the selection of a combobox, so if combobox1.get () == "Item1". The 2 + 2 == 4 was just an example because I wanted to understand how to write a condition in the same line. ::::QUESTION::::: In reference to your answer, should I write (f "{b}" if if combobox1.get () == "Item1" else "") + \? Or is there another solution? I'm waiting for your answer. Thank you

Comment: @SantiagoE.98 I appreciate you trying to simplify things. Most of the details in your last comment probably don't matter to understand your question. However, I think you go a bit too far in simplifying by making a condition that will always be true. You could easily use a variable or function as a place holder for the condition such as `if is_foo()` to convey the idea. As for solving the problem, don't do everything in one statement. Break up your logic into smaller steps and use multiple statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one of operator precedence. String concatenation (implied or explicit using `+`) has higher precedence than `if-else` (see the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)) so your expression evaluates as:

```py
x = (f"{a}" f"{b}") if 2+2==4 else ("" f"{c}")
```

which will yield either `"Hello. I'm Santy"` or `" and i love Python"`. To make `c` dependent on the condition, you *must* parenthesise that condition and make it apply *only* to `c` (note I've substituted `True` for your condition for simplicity):

```py
x = f"{a}" f"{b}" + (f"{c}" if True else "")
```

Output:

```
"Hello. I'm Santy and i love Python"
```

Note that you need to use a `+` before the condition as a parenthesised expression is not a string literal which can be concatenated without an operator.

Then the `False` condition:

```py
x = f"{a}" f"{b}" + (f"{c}" if False else "")
```

Output:

```
"Hello. I'm Santy"
```

Written as multi-line code:

```py
x = f"{a}" + \
    f"{b}" + \
    (f"{c}" if False else "")
```

Comment: I understand. What if you don't want to write the two quotes (> ""), but use another solution? I just need "if 2 + 2 == 4"

Comment: @SantiagoE.98 I'm not sure what you mean about not writing the two quotes? If you have an `if`, you must have an `else`

Comment: But you can put anything you like in place of the `""`

Comment: Is writing otherwise required for the code? I'm only interested in 2 + 2 == 4. Can I NOT write else?

Comment: @SantiagoE.98 no. An `if` *expression* must have an `else`. The only way to do it without an else would be as an `if` *statement* e.g. `x = f"{a}" f"{b}"; if 2+2==4: x+=f"{c}"`

Answer (score -1):

The `f"{c}"` and the `f"{b}" if 2+2 == 4 else ""` are "joined up". You can fix this by changing it to:

```
f"{a}" \
    f"{b}"f"{c}" if 2+2 == 4 else "" \
```

Or:

```
f"{a}" \
    (f"{b}" if 2+2 == 4 else "") + f"{c}"
```

Comment: I wrote this solution in my question, but I wrote that I don't need this solution. I don't need it because I have so many other placeholders (which I didn't write in the question) and I would like to write the code as readable as possible. Thanks anyway

Comment: @SantiagoE.98 To write code as readable as possible, don't try to do so much in a single line. I suggest using `+` to concatenate strings together and `if` statements to decide what parts to concatenate.

Comment: @Santiago E. 98, then, it would be best to use concatention.

Comment: Why is this upvoted? The first solution doesn't work and the second won't even parse